# In my Web Api how to write code for if MobileItems(Parent Class) in which a single mobile item has AccessoryItems(Child)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
    public class MobileItems
        {

            public int MobileItemsId { get; set; }

            public string MobileName { get; set; }

            public int MobilePrice { get; set; }

            public string isAccessory { get; set; }
            public List<AccessoryItems> AccessoryItems { get; set; }
        }



    }
```

This is my Parent Model MobileItems in which i have to create a method which checks for every mobile that it has belonging accessory or not if it has then print yes or else no

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the item class and not the class that collects all of the mobiles.

```
public class MobileItems
{
    public int MobileItemsId { get; set; }

    public string MobileName { get; set; }

    public int MobilePrice { get; set; }

    public bool hasAccessory
    {
        get
        {
            return AccessoryItems.Any();
        }
    }
    public List<AccessoryItems> AccessoryItems { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that I changed **isAccessory** to **hasAccessory**, because (if I understand things correctly) the mobile **is** not an accessory, it **has** an accessory.

**hasAccessory** will return true if there is any object in the *AccessoryItems* list. Be careful with null though. You probably wanna initialize *AccessoryItems* in the constructor to prevent future exceptions.

You can use this in some other class or method in order to select what to print.

```
public void PrintMobileHasAccessory(List<MobileItems> mobiles)
{
    foreach (MobileItems mobile in mobiles)
    {
        if (mobile.hasAccessory)
            Console.WriteLine("yes");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no");
    }
}
```